# LinqToExcel "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" - how to capture the details?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-excel

I am using LinqToExcel to import large Excel data sheet into SQL Server database table Employees2. I am using EF4. The Date field in Excel (DOB and many other) is in "MMddyyyy" format. I have many fields in Excel, I just show 1 mapping here.

---

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelPath);
excel.AddMapping<Employee2>(x => x.DOB, "DOB", 
s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? DateTime.MinValue : 
DateTime.ParseExact(s, @"MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat));

var employees = excel.Worksheet<Employee2>("Sheet1").ToList();
employees.ForEach(e => context.Employee2.AddObject(e));
context.SaveChanges();
```

---

The code throws exception "**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**"

on this line of code:
    var employees = excel.Worksheet("Sheet1").ToList();

**My question is: How can I capture which record exactly causes the exception?**

The exception doesn't say which record or even which field.

Just to make sure the conversion is fine, in command window I ran:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("08012012", "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat)
```

**Update:**

Found the solution myself:
[EF Exception: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380972/ef-exception-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-the-statement-has-been-t)

Comment: Debug with F5, it will break on exception, see s find the value of s in your excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Does the column DOB not just return DateTime values?

Comment: I fails to see any connection between your question and the solution you found. Did you copy a wrong link?

Comment: Oh, the DateTime issue - it was something else. Empty area of Excel sheet was loaded, the excel cell was empty, no date value... 

The real problem is when you call SaveChanges - I got multiple exceptions that I mentioned in the post in that link.

My question was: How can I capture which record exactly causes the exception? And the solution - SQL Profiler, you cant do this using EF.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download the [source code for LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel) and re-run the query using the source code. Then you can break on the exception and see the actual row and value that is causing the issue.

Comment: Why? This exception seems to happen in his code - in the lambda expression. Should be able to see details without having to download anything.